# diagnosing why java on Centos (Tomcat) using 150% CPU while idle - JConsole?

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

the Java process on my Tomcat/Centos server is taking 150% CPU while idle (no one logged in to our application)

```
 PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU  %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                            
16917 administ  20   0 8936m 470m  12m S 141.8  3.0  22:29.31 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java
```

I can connect to the java instance using JConsole, I can see a list of the Threads which are running, but how can I determine which Threads/Tasks are using all the CPU?
NOTE: The CPU problem doesn't seem to be due to GC.

Is there perhaps an MBean I can call?

Comment: Is this recent? Could simply be the leapsecond issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you use JVisualVM you can see which threads are active and get a stack trace of those threads.

You can also enable CPU monitoring but this will slow down your application. (If its not being used much that should be fine)

Comment: I like VisualVM - but in this case the problem was the leap-second bug in Java on Linux.  Thanks anyway